# PHP: Fetching lines from a text file

Tags: php

**Edit:** I've learned much since the posting of this question, and so I have rewritten it for anyone who similarly inquires.

I'm attempting to load a specified number of lines from the end of a text file via a HTTP GET request, which will be sent to a PHP file. Can this be done with `file_get_contents()`?

The function `file_get_contents()` also reads the entire file into memory. What is a more efficient solution than reading the entire file to array, then removing the specified number of lines?

For example, if I had a 12000 line text file, how would I read the range of lines between 4025-6042?

Comment: eh? What have you tried?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will read the whole file, which could be split into lines, but may waste resources.  Instead look into `fopen(), fread()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [`file()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the file as an array. Then [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) to prune the array.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) you can specify an `offset` and a `maxlength` into your `file_get_contents` to specify how much of the file to read.

> This function is similar to file(), except that file_get_contents() returns the file in a string, **starting at the specified offset up to maxlen bytes.**

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that the calculations are done in number of bytes and not number of lines.

Comment: @nickb I see how that could make things difficult, but it doesn't mean it's impossible.